# ¿Recorrer y marcar radiobuttons mediante javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema que no resuelvo, tengo 5 radiobuttons los cuales quiero que vayan marcando cada uno por turno.

```
function efecto(){

    let radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

    for(let j=0; j<radio.length;j++){ 
        if(radio[j].checked==false){
            radio[j].checked=true;
        }else{
            radio[j].checked=false;
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',function(){ 
    setInterval(efecto,1000); 
});
```

Hice esto y lo único que logro es que se marque al final, quisiera que se vayan marcando uno por uno como un juego de luces, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo bien qué es lo que deseas obtener, que todos se marquen y desmarquen al mismo tiempo, que se marquen por turnos (como juego de luces) o que todos queden marcados.

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona bien tu codigo, salvo que le falta un parentesis al final para cerrar el addEventListener. Si eso soluciona tu problema, recuerda revisar la consola para ver los errores

Comment: @Vlady Si exacto que se marquen por turnos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no pusiste tu HTML hice un ejemplo de lo que quizás quieres obtener:

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
let radioActual = 0;

function efecto(){
  radio[radioActual].checked = true;
  radioActual = ++radioActual >= radio.length ? 0 : radioActual;
}

window.addEventListener('load',function(){ 
    setInterval(efecto,1000); 
});
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radios" />Radio 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radios" />Radio 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radios" />Radio 3</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radios" />Radio 4</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radios" />Radio 5</label>
```

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba,muchas gracias @Vlady